SQLite DELETE WHERE IN gives a SQL logic error with no further information
Have a situation where the current select works fine,
SELECT * FROM
    servers
WHERE
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT server_id
        FROM
            server_polls
    );

but changing to a DELETE gives a  SQL Logic Error
DELETE FROM
    servers
WHERE
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT server_id
        FROM
            server_polls
            
    );

with nothing more to go on.  Same error happens in code and DB Browser for SQLite so it's obviously a me issue but don't see a path forward.

After running your delete statement, try typing commit; and Enter. After that, see if any data was removed.

Is that the full error message? Can you try reproducing it in a fresh database (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

I've tried to recreate this with DB Browser without success: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dzqFcUjZly8Tauqaq-SXsC4O55eDQcY5?usp=drive_link Since these queries work fine in my db, can you upload a db file which shows the issue please?

Are servers and server_polls both tables (as opposed to views)?

@JohnBollinger yes they are tables

Can you show us the table definitions?

It looks like it's related to ON DELETE CASCADE in table creation
